# Altium tells me: Off Grid Net

Tags: altium

When I compile my project in Altium, I get a warning telling me I have a label off the grid.

Does anybody know how can I correct this warning in one go, without replacing all the nets one by one?

Which grid size do you usually use when you draw a schematic?

[image]

Comment: A screenshot might help.

Comment: @AHB   sorry I forgot it, here it is in the edit

Comment: One way is to turn off this warning.

Comment: yes but if i turn off everytime there is an error, then i will not know this an error... the question is how to avoid this error...

Comment: It is a warning not an error. And if you do **not want to** modify your components and redraw the nets, then make sure that there are no floating nets/labels at these pins and that you have wired everything to these pins you wanted. Warning does not means that it is wrong, only there is a higher possibility so you should double or triple check it.

Comment: The error messages give you the coordinates of the error location.  You just have to go to those coordinates to find and fix the error.

Answer (score 3):

The most common cause of this issue is that you are using components designed on, say, a metric grid but your schematic is on a standard grid (or vice versa). You can change the schematic grid by opening the schematic, go to Design --> Document Options, click the Units tab and select the checkbox next to "Use ____ Unit System" (select the one that is not currently selected). Make sure the grid itself matches the grid that the components were created on (in the libraries).

If the problem persists (just with different off-grid pins this time) then chances are you have some components created on a metric grid and some created on a standard grid. This is one of the reasons why I recommend ALWAYS making your own libraries, rather than using third-party ones. You just can't get consistency from using multiple third-party libraries.

Your best bet would be to build a new library and recreate the components you are using. Make sure they're all created on the same grid that you want your final schematic to be on, and use your custom library exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

Align your pins so that they are always on a grid in your schematic. If you use the default templates, this will always be on a multitude of 5 DXP units or 50 mils (those are equivalent). Once you do this, you won't have problems with nets off grid or faulty connections. So - correct the components and re-draw the nets.

Answer (score 0):

Use 50 mil = 1.27 cm for schematic grid.
Component connections use this usually. So using a different grid lead to connection problems.
Go to the schema editor, then to the properties panel and set BOTH "visible grid" and "snap grid" to the above value. This avoids plenty of issues you get if you use a different grid for a schema.
If you have some parts off-grid, i.e. misaligned, select them, cut them, and paste again. This way you can align them to the grid.