# Off grid pin message at Altium17

Tags: altium

I'm always got 'off grid pin' message on my schematic. The pin on the symbol is built by me, using a component wizard. I already set my units on the library and schematic on same units. I have tried to move the pin on my own too, and the message is still there. Anyone can help me?

*I've tried the answer from [Altium tell me Off Grid Net](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/239827/altium-tell-me-off-grid-net/239870)

picture : 
1. from library 
2. from schematic
3. the message

[image: from library]
[image: from schematic]
[image: the message]

Comment: This is really hard to answer without a picture of at least one of the pins in question from both the library and the schematic.

Comment: Make sure your grids are the same in both the library and the schematic, NEVER change them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error (or warning, depending on your settings) appears when the pins of a component do not lay precisely on the document grid. This is most commonly caused by a different grid being used to draw the schematic than what was used to draw the component symbol in the library. I suggest going into your SCH Library, find the component in question, change the grid to your standard schematic document grid, and redraw the component (or at least move the pins so that they sit perfectly on the grid). Then in your schematic document either re-add the component or go to `Tools --> Update From Libraries` and select the component to update.

Comment: thank you. The problem cannot be solved because i try to move a group of pin. The problem is solved by move the pin one-by-one to the grid.

Comment: You can use Edit » Align » Align To Grid to move selected objects back to the grid respectively a new grid.

Comment: @Manu3l0us I don't believe that helps if the pins on a given part were placed on a different grid (i.e. metric vs. imperial). It will only move the component so that its origin is positioned on the new grid. It does not re-align the individual pins.

Comment: @DerStrom8 You will have to open the library containing the part, change the grid settings to the target grid and then do the alignment. Minor corrections will be needed probably. I once had a library from a client using the metric grid which I had to convert for using it together with our "imperial" grid library and schematics (which is the default in Altium and most libs use that).